# Sequence to study Mathematics from beginning to Undergraduate Level

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, arithmetic

I had the misfortune of a late diagnosed leaning impairment cause a few gaps in my knowledge which resulted in flawed foundational knowledge needed to progress efficiently and effectively.

I'm pursuing **Applied Mathematics** and Physics at Bachelor Degree Level and will possibly add Pure Mathematics later on.

My Question:
**What is the best/easiest sequence to learn/relearn maths from Elementary/Primary level up to a Bachelor/Masters Level**? My reason behind this is that I want to correct all gaps in my mathematical knowledge and progress to the highest level attainable.

My reasoning is that I am already aware that If your Algebra is flawed, You may struggle with Trigonometry etc.

Please list the items/ Topics/ Sub-topics

I would Appreciate any help.

Comment: Make sure you know/understand basic arithmetic, everything in algebra is an extension of these concepts. Once you have arithmetic mastered, move on to basic algebra and geometry (some concepts get intertwined here naturally, so it makes sense to study them at relatively the same pace). After that, statistics and trigonometry, then calculus. From there, the road broadens rather substantially, so there is no one set path (not that there is for lower-level math either, but it is more universally-accepted that one understand arithmetic before tackling algebra, e.g.).

Comment: Basic Euclidean geometry (junior high school and high school), some analytic geometry, trigonometry, advanced analytic geometry, vectors, etc. In algebra: basic linear equations in one and two variables, quadratic equations and functions, sequences (arithmetic and geometric ones), elementary functions and their graphs, logarithms, exponential functions, induction, Newton's binomial theorem...More or less. You could read some books' contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you've had basic schooling in math, since you refer to "a few gaps" in your knowledge, not a wholesale lack. In that case, the first thing to do is assess how good your current knowledge is.

I suggest starting with a pre-algebra book that has an answer key. Work the problems and see if you get the right answers. If you miss many, you should study the concepts needed for pre-algebra, because those will provide the [foundational knowledge of topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-algebra) you'll need for beginning algebra.

Once you're confident in pre-algebra, time to move on to beginning algebra. If you've had algebra, again try an assessment first. See if you can get the answers to problems, that'll let you know how thoroughly you'll have to study this topic.

After algebra, try introductory geometry, assessing your knowledge there and filling it in as necessary. Continue with more advanced high-school algebra, which should include trigonometry.

Precalculus is essentially advanced high-school algebra. Depending on which book(s) you use, you may cover some of the same topics as algebra/trigonometry but at a more advanced level.

Calculus is next. High-school calculus covers the same topics as introductory calculus at the college level, but at a slower pace. Calculus teaches about limits, derivatives, integrals, and various types of methods for evaluating and working with those with respect to different types of functions. Here you'll make use of concepts you learned in algebra/trigonometry/pre-caclulus.

Once you've got through calculus, you should consider differential equations, discrete math, linear algebra, and some kind of analysis (probably real analysis).

Mastering all of those should open things up for you to more advanced topics in math and physics.